# Having trouble getting text input working on imacro

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to record a macro with text input, but whenever it gets up to entering the text, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: element INPUT specified by ID:ctrl699077237575BF0A8F14562A1C861DE76E16F42BA592707587115627BCDE1D8831F90660D4D3C18832F46AF95CFDBC99 was not found, line 6 (Error code: -921)

Here is the macro I am trying to get working. Please share your thoughts.

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.simplyenergy.com.au/pay-my-bill/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Credit<SP>Card
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmMain ATTR=ID:ctrl699077237575BF0A8F14562A1C861DE76E16F42BA592707587115627BCDE1D8831F90660D4D3C18832F46AF95CFDBC99 CONTENT=Test<SP>123
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmMain ATTR=ID:ctrl40430E5B2B6C22C79DAAC192280DCD94AB9086F07518E7F9EB6990B64A77B57EFAA5B281D3E99CBE0BA543CC8AD9C10A CONTENT=Test<SP>123
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmMain ATTR=ID:ctrl699077237575BF0A8F14562A1C861DE792B18ADFEC66456C7F128AB6AA513AE0C6B291CFA6EE3A4378214EA839681B77 CONTENT=Test<SP>123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in the following way:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.simplyenergy.com.au/pay-my-bill/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Credit<SP>Card
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmMain ATTR=ID:ctrl* CONTENT=Test<SP>123
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmMain ATTR=ID:ctrl* CONTENT=Test<SP>123
TAG POS=3 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmMain ATTR=ID:ctrl* CONTENT=Test<SP>123
```